# SQL query does not work when called by window.location.href

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

When i select an option I call a Javascript code with the onchange function.
I send 2 parameters with it:

```
//capaciteit.php
function testfunction(week, id)
{
window.location.href = "capaciteitberekening.php?week=" + week + "&id=" + id;
}
```

I call the file capaciteitberekening.php and send the parameters with it.
then I try to get the both parameters with the $_GET function:

```
//capaciteitberekening.php
require ('capaciteit.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$week = $_GET['week'];
echo $id, $week;
```

After I echo both $id and $week(to check if they are working) I call a query:

```
//capaciteitberekening.php
$datumbegin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM capaciteit");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($datumbegin))
{
echo $row['DAGEN'];
}
```

When I try this on my website its only shows the echo of $id and $week.

this code is working code since I use it somewhere else and it works fine there.

this is the way i connect to my DB:

```
require('auth.php');require_once('config.php');require_once('exec/pubs_exec.php');
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);   //Database openen
    if(!$link) die('Niet gelukt om verbinding te maken met de server: ' . mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);                     //Select database
    if(!$db) die("Selecteren van DB mislukt");
```

in config.php i set the values for DB_host, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD and DB_DATABASE

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" Well you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions. But besides that nothing is wrong with this code that lies somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have opened the `MySql` monnection? Try to enable error output with `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Either you haven't made a connection to the database, or the query returns no results

Comment: Apache? -> /var/log/apache2/error.log (usually )

Comment: You never bothered checking if the query actually succeeded. `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` should be the absolute bare minimum error handling you need.

Comment: It says that my $datumbegin isnt 1 so i assume its empty, I am opening the DB correctly since i use it multiple times and the code works on other pages. the only thing here is different is that I call via javascript

Comment: I always use this way:  $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql ) or trigger_error( mysqli_error( $conn ) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the mysql_* methods, as they have been [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) since PHP 5.5. ([A more thorough explanation](http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/1272-your-mysql-code-sucks/) of how to go from the mysql_* library to PDO).

To actually also answer your question, you probably don't have errors enabled on your website and don't see the error that occurs when the mysql connection fails (which stops execution of the PHP script at the line it occurs at)